# How to call a ndarray in another function in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, math

So I'm trying to make some basic root finding functions for a school project, here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 3)
f = 14 * x * np.exp(x - 2) - 12 * np.exp(x - 2) - 7 * x ** 3 + 20 * x ** 2 - 26 * x + 12

def bolzano(function, lower, upper):
    if function(lower) * function(upper) < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def bisection(function, lower, upper):
    m = (lower + upper) / 2
    while function(m) > 10 ** -6:
        if bolzano(function, lower, m):
            upper = m
        else:
            lower = m
        m = (lower + upper) / 2
    return float(m)


b = bisection(f, 0, 3)
print(b)
```

However when I try to run it, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test.py", line 31, in <module>
     b = bisection(f, 0, 3)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test.py", line 22, in 
     bisection while function(m) > 10 ** -6:
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I tried casting elements in the bisection function to known data types but it didn't do the job. Most posts about ndarrays are about... well, arrays, which I don't use, so no luck in finding a solution there.
Any ideas?

Comment: `x` is a `ndarray`, created by the `np.linspace` function.  `f` is also a `ndarray`, created by doing math on `x`.  Try a `print(f)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function definition `f` is not a function at the moment. It is just an expression right now. You have two options: Either use `SymPy` or just create a function for evaluating `f` so that you can simply call it using a normal function call as `f(x)` where `x` is your argument which can either be an array or a single number. Below is how you would do it using the second option.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 3)

def f(x):
    return 14 * x * np.exp(x - 2) - 12 * np.exp(x - 2) - 7 * x ** 3 + 20 * x ** 2 - 26 * x + 12

# bolzano function here

# bisection function here

b = bisection(f, 0, 3)
print(b)
# 1.5
```

Since you are evaluating your function for scalar inputs, as pointed out by @hpaulj, you are better off with using `math.exp` instead of `np.exp`. The former expects only scalar input unlike the latter which also accepts vectors.

Comment: The `x` created by the `linespace` isn't used.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for the comment. I am not even sure if it's needed. If you look at the OP's code, he/she is just using it to compute the function at a given value of x which is represented by `m`.

Comment: `math.exp` might be better.  It's faster when given scalars, and doesn't return an array.

Comment: @hpaulj:. Thanks again. I added your suggestion